# how to display drop down next to he elevated button

Tags: flutter

this is two search and dropdown sections I have implemented using `animated_custom_dropdown.`

I want that "Get Quote Filter " button to place next to the(right side) set location drop down..................................................................................................................................

........................................................................................................................................

```
import 'package:animated_custom_dropdown/custom_dropdown.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import '../constants/colors.dart';



const _labelStyle = TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600);

class FantomSearch extends StatefulWidget {
  const FantomSearch({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FantomSearch> createState() => _FantomSearchState();
}

class _FantomSearchState extends State<FantomSearch> {
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final List<String> list = ['Heating', 'Electricians', 'Repair or Service', 'Accessibility Planner'];

  final jobRoleFormDropdownCtrl = TextEditingController(),
      jobRoleSearchDropdownCtrl = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    jobRoleFormDropdownCtrl.dispose();
    jobRoleSearchDropdownCtrl.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      //backgroundColor:AppGreen,
      appBar: AppBar(
        systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark.copyWith(
          statusBarColor: AppGreen,
        ),
        backgroundColor: AppGreen,
        elevation: .10,
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: 200,
        color: AppGreen,
        child: ListView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          children: [
            CustomDropdown.search(
              hintText: 'Search Services',
              items: list,
              controller: jobRoleSearchDropdownCtrl,
              fillColor: DarkGreen,

            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 24),
            // using form for validation
            Form(
              key: formKey,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 150),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    CustomDropdown(
                      hintText: 'Set Location',
                      items: list,
                      controller: jobRoleFormDropdownCtrl,
                      excludeSelected: false,
                      fillColor: DarkGreen,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 16),
                    SizedBox(
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (!formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                            return;
                          }
                        },
                        child: const Text(
                          'Get Quotes filter',
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                        ),
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: ContainerGreen),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, I believe that currently "**Get quotes filter**" showing below to the "**Set Location**" correct?

If this is the issue, you need to update **Column** widget to **Row** which is inside **Padding**.

Like,

```
Container(
    height: 200,
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          /**/
        Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: CustomDropdown.search(
                hintText: 'Search Services',
                items: list,
                controller: jobRoleSearchDropdownCtrl,
                fillColor: DarkGreen,

              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, top: 20, right: 15, bottom: 20),
              child: Text(
                "cancel"
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
          const SizedBox(height: 24),
          // using form for validation
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 70),
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                /**/
                Expanded(
                  child: CustomDropdown(
                    hintText: 'Set Location',
                    items: list,
                    controller: jobRoleFormDropdownCtrl,
                    excludeSelected: false,
                    fillColor: DarkGreen,
                  ),
                ),

                const SizedBox(width: 16),
                SizedBox(
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (!formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                        return;
                      }
                    },
                    child: const Text(
                      'Get Quotes filter',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                    ),
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.green),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  )
```

If this still not worked, please share the expected output and what you are getting now. Because I am not able to compile your code due to custom widgets.

I have updated the color so please update it as per your need. The output is something like,

[image]

Comment: I have uploaded the image of how its displays. I tried your suggestion converting to a Row also doesn't work. >> the error is RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderFocusTrapArea#ef6f1 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Comment: No I mean please upload two images 1. What do you want to achieve 2. How it is displaying.

Comment: kindly check the question. just now uploaded

Comment: Please check updated code.

Comment: it's working now. thank you so much for the support. good luck with your work